# Select element(s) without specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi this is my problem:

```
<ul>
   <li><span class="show">*</span>Show</li>
   <li><span class="show">*</span>Show</li>
   <li><span class="show">*</span>Show</li>
   <li><span class="show">*</span>Show</li>
   <li>Hide</li>
   <li>Hide</li>
</ul>
```

So oposite of this http://jsfiddle.net/ajitam/GqCpW/

How can I select (with jQuery) 'li's without span.show inside.

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Selector should look like this:

```
$('ul li:not(:has(span.show))')
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Mkj7Z/

Since such a selector is pretty expensive, make sure you cache the resulting DOM nodes in a variable for further access.

Answer (score 0):

Try hiding all, then showing those which have `span.show`

```
$('ul li').hide().find('span.show').parent().show();
```

Comment: Yes thats one way but I must use slideToggle, so this method is out of the question

Answer (score 0):

jAndy's solution, `$('ul li:not(:has(span.show))')` works well but `:not` and `:has` are generally poor performing selectors (and he points out that they are expensive).  Looking at your markup, is it possible to select the `<li>` elements based on their text?

```
// Using `:contains` we can look for *Hide*
$('ul > li:contains("Hide")')

// Or using `filter()` for an exact match
$('ul > li').filter(function () {
    return $.text(this) === "Hide";
});
```

This is a little faster and a little neater.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$('ul li').filter(function(){
     return $('.show',this).length==0;
});
```

You can extend the filter to more complex queries.